# Block garbage collector while analyzing weak references

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm experimenting with WeakReference, and I'm writing a code that checks if a weak reference is valid before returning a strong reference to the object.

```
if (weakRef.IsValid)
    return (ReferencedType)weakRef.Target;
else
    // Build a new object
```

How should I prevent the GC collecting the object between the "IsValid" and the "Target" calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should instead do something like this:

```
var rt = weakRef.Target as ReferencedType;

if (rt != null)
    // You now have a strong reference that you can safely use
```

If you succeed in obtaining a strong reference then you are assured that it will not be collected by the GC. A more complete example is provided in MSDN [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) page and if you haven't read it already you also may find useful the following:

[Weak References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx)

Comment: This seems to me the most "natural" way to go. For completeness, it requires the use of short weak references, which in my case is not a problem.

Comment: +1 cause it is the only way to be sure. But i don't think that you need to cast it to the needed `ReferenceType`. You could also obtain it as `object` and make the null-validity-check on this. Depending on what you like to do with the object next it makes maybe sense, but it is not needed to be sure the instance is alive.